# Symfony2 storing a PNG image in database using Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, png

I have a Symfony2 application that uses KendoUI. I am using Symfony to create some KendoUI objects which are then sent to the browser where the Kendo JavaScript library takes over and renders an SVG image. Then, there is a method in the Kendo javascript library that generates a PNG image from the SVG graphic. I wish to persist this PNG image.

What I would like to do is allow a user to create and configure a Symfony entity, which is then converted to a KendoUI object which is then rendered in the browser by Kendo. If the user is happy, they can then click a button to create a PNG "thumbnail" of their image. I then would like to save the PNG thumbnail as a property of the Symfony entity.

I have is a form with a textarea field called "thumbnail", and when the Kendo image is rendered, a button click successfully writes the PNG image (as a string starting "data:image/png;base64") into the form field. My question regards how best to persist this image data for the thumbnail using Doctrine, so I can retrieve the PNG image and show it in the browser.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you not to store images in the database. Why do you want to store it there? What kind of DB? From Doctrine I suppose MySql or Mongo?

Comment: I wish to store in the image in the database for these reasons; when the entity is deleted, the image needs to be deleted as well; I wish the image to obey ROLLBACK commands; I need to ensure that only certain users can access the image; I am using Doctrine extensions so users can revert to previous versions of saved entities.

Comment: It is a MySQL database.